# Regex to replace first and last lines?

Tags: regex

I used `\A.*$\r\n` to remove first line in text, using Powergrep,
Is there a way to multiply this command? Need to select and remove first 3 lines in text, and last 3 lines in text?

Tried this solution [Perl/regex to remove first 3 lines and last 3 lines of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7047205/perl-regex-to-remove-first-3-lines-and-last-3-lines-of-a-string) but it doesn't work in Powergrep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this pattern:

```
\A(.*\r?\n){3}|(\r?\n.*){3}\z
```

Test it with Rubular here: http://rubular.com/r/MfiF4tRyk3

Comment: I tested in Powergrep, I confirm this one worked, the one from first answer didn't, thank you both for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Check this for the first three lines ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/dP8sT2/3) on regex101.com):

```
\A(^.*$\r?\n){3}
```

and this for the last three ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/dP8sT2/4)):

```
(^.*$\r?\n){3}\z
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use *grep* for that.  **grep(1)** works in a *line equality* assuption.  You have a better solution with **sed(1)** in the following code:

```
sed -e '1d;$d' file.txt >output.txt
```

I you want to delete lines `1-3` and `($-3)-$` try

```
sed -e '1,3d;$-3,$d' file.txt >output.txt
```

Sorry, I have never used **powergrep** so I cannot help you in that way.